# Create media item and specify item id

Tags: media-library, sitecore-api

I have a scenario where I need site visitors to be able to upload media items via `CD` server. My plan is to upload to `web` database first and  use `EventQueues` to then have the `CM` server fetch the serialized media item and write it to the `master` database.

For this approach to be viable though I need to be able to specify the `master` instance of the item's id to match the `web` instance.

Currently to create media items I have the following extension method...

```
public static MediaItem CreateMediaItem(this Item parentItem, HttpPostedFileBase file, Sitecore.Data.Database database)
{
    try
    {
        var fileName = ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName));

        var options = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions
        {
            Database = database,
            Destination = parentItem.Paths.Path + "/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName),
            IncludeExtensionInItemName = false,
            KeepExisting = true,
            Versioned = false,
            FileBased = false,
            AlternateText = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName)
        };

        var creator = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator();

        return (MediaItem)creator.CreateFromStream(file.InputStream, file.FileName, options);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
            //handle it
    }
}
```

Is there any way to utilize `MediaCreator` to specify what I want the id to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I know, it's not possible with `MediaCreator` class.

What you could try instead is to create an item first using `ItemManager` like:

```
Item newItem = ItemManager.CreateItem(newItemName, parentItem, templateID, newItemID);
```

And then use `MediaCreator.AttachStreamToMediaItem` method with

```
MediaCreatorOptions.KeepExisting = false;
// or better
MediaCreatorOptions.OverwriteExisting = true;
```

Your code will first create the empty media item with specific ID and then will override it with the data from the stream.

Comment: Thanks Marek, I'll give this a try and report back

Comment: I've found a `MediaCreator.AttachStreamToMediaItem()` method, looks like it is what I'm after when using your suggestion. If you want to update your answer I'll accept :)

Comment: Answer updated.